# SonarQube. Parse error in CROSS APPLY with union but all looks good

Tags: sql, sql-server, sonarqube

I have file with sql function about 1k lines. Sonar throws an error on this file. The code itself works without errors. Here is a general view of the request where the error. Parse error message points to symbol above '^'

```
 INSERT INTO foo
SELECT
  ...
FROM foo
JOIN ..
JOIN ...
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)
    ...
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY ..
  UNION
  ^
  SELECT TOP (1) 
    ...
  FROM ...
  JOIN ...
  JOIN ...
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY ...
) pp
```

Comment: `UNION` concatenates two or more result sets - it doesn't make sense to have `ORDER BY` clauses in any of the source result sets, it can only work for the final output of the `UNION`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i think its not like that. Because we take only top 1 node, in that case order by make scene

Answer (score 0):

```
      INSERT INTO foo
        SELECT
          ...
        FROM foo
        JOIN ..
        JOIN ...
        CROSS APPLY ((SELECT TOP (1)
            ...
          FROM ...
          WHERE ...
          ORDER BY ..)
          UNION
          ^
(          SELECT TOP (1) 
            ...
          FROM ...
          JOIN ...
          JOIN ...
          WHERE ...
          ORDER BY ..)
        ) pp
```

Comment: @Ivas1256 you are right. With top you can use order by. Can you please share  the actual query? Problem may exist in some place else. Please try to execute the query without union and one condition at a time in cross apply and watch what happened. And would you please try enclosing both the condition in first bracket () union ().